# Exporting and Reusing Variables (azure devops)

Tags: variables, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a dynamically created variable inside a CI Pipeline, let's call it "*var: $(version.number).$(Date:yyyyMMdd)*". I wish to reuse this as a part of the Publish Test Results task in a CD Pipeline so I can link both together and have a valid reference. But I can't fathom how to do this.

This is the yaml for the Publish Test Results task in it's most basic form.

```
steps:
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/TEST-*.xml'
```

Any pointers will be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could write it out to a json/xml file via power shell task, and publish the file as artifacts. Then read in that file via PowerShell in your release definition.

Build Definition

```
ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "file.json"
```

Release Definition

```
Get-Content "file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Also, we could pass the variable from build to release via the extension [Variable Tools for Azure DevOps Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration).

Steps:

Build Definition and result

[image]

Release Definition and result

[image]

In addition, I found a blog and save the variable to csv file, you could also refer to [Passing variables in VSTS, from Build to Release and between environments](https://medium.com/@jonoble/passing-variables-in-vsts-from-build-to-release-and-between-environments-640169588175).

Comment: Thank you Vito, this is a brilliant explanation!